# Access JSON elements

Tags: javascript, json

I'm pretty new to JSON and unsure how to access the arrays within my result.  I want to store the coordinates in 3 seperate javascript arrays.  How do I access the coordinates?

Here is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'urlhere.php',
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (data) {
  }
});
```

`data.routes` gets me close, but I'm struggling to access `data.routes.route_parts.coordinates`, if that makes sense:

```
{
  "request_time": "2016-08-02T20:32:31+01:00",
  "routes": [
    {
      "duration": "01:46:00",
      "route_parts": [
        {
          "mode": "foot",
          "from_point_name": "specified point",
          "to_point_name": "ABC",
          "destination": "",
          "line_name": "",
          "duration": "00:05:00",
          "departure_time": "06:12",
          "arrival_time": "06:17",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              -12.72212,
              53.64521
            ],
            [
              -12.72212,
              53.6452
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "mode": "bus",
          "line_name": "113",
          "duration": "00:28:00",
          "departure_time": "06:17",
          "arrival_time": "06:45",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              -12.72419,
              53.64403
            ],
            [
              -12.72412,
              53.64405
            ],
            [
              -12.72412,
              53.64405
            ],
            [
              -12.48062,
              53.70897
            ],
            [
              -12.48051,
              53.70881
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "mode": "foot",
          "duration": "00:07:00",
          "departure_time": "08:53",
          "arrival_time": "09:00",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              -12.48042,
              53.70883
            ],
            [
              -12.4805,
              53.7088
            ],
            [
              -12.48033,
              53.70857
            ]
          ]
        }
      ],
      "departure_time": "06:56",
      "departure_date": "2016-08-03",
      "arrival_time": "09:00",
      "arrival_date": "2016-08-03"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `data.routes[0].route_parts`

Answer (score 0):

use indexes to access data.

```
data.routes.route_parts[0].coordinates
```